# How render react components from array

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have several components.

formFields/index.js

```
export {default as description} from './description/description.component'
export {default as title} from './title/title.component'
```

I import them and get a list of FormFields in mainComponent

```
import * as FormFields from '../formFields'
```

How can I use them in render function?

This is one of my failed attempts:

```
import * as FormFields from '../formFields'

render() {

  let properties = ['description', 'title'];

  let getComponent = (type) => {
    let formElement = FormFields[type]
    return <formElement/>
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {properties.map((property, i) => {
        return (
          <div key={i}>
            {getComponent(property)}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

This experiment is successful:

```
render() {
  let EditComponent = FormFields['description']
  return (
    <div>
      <EditComponent/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example that also passes the same props. It is essentially an array of components that you map and then, simply render.

```js
class Description extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.prop}</div>;
  }
}

class Title extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.prop}</div>;
  }
}

const myComponents = [
  Description,
  Title,
];

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {myComponents.map((FormField, i) => <FormField key={i} prop="Hello World!" /> )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="View"></div>
```

Comment: don't forget to add a key prop :)